# Constant gravitational field

Tags: newtonian-gravity

When we take two magnets place one on table and slowly bring other magnet closer, the first magnet responses very slowly then as we bring it closer it accelerates suddenly towards the second magnet. It is as if the magnetic force is not constant. We don’t see this happening in case of gravity. Is this because the force of gravity constant for some height?

Comment: We **do** see gravity varying with distance; that's why orbits are elliptical. But when objects fall near Earth's surface, the distance from its centre of mass varies _very_ little.

Comment: The friction from the magnet on the table it's the main cause of the stuttered attraction. Try hanging the magnet from a string and you will see a smoother pull following the inverse Square rule discussed in the answers.

Comment: @J.G. To understand how the orbit is eliptical I watched some videos and it says it’s the balance of gravity vs speed and distance. So if I am right the earth deaccelerates as it moves further away from sun. This decreases its velocity and now the earth turns back and accelerates towards the sun. It gets sling shot again away from the sun. This is how the eliptical orbit develops. Right?

Comment: No, an elliptical orbit with the central mass at its focus [only happens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation) if the force is of the form $A/r^2+B/r^3$. If the force didn't vary with distance, you [wouldn't even get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem) a stable closed orbit.

Comment: A similar effect is a plug and drain. Fill a tub with water, remove the plug, and hold it about four inches away. Slowly move it toward the drain and you will feel the force accelerate as you get closer until it eventually grabs the plug and holds it in place.

Comment: @J.G. I didn’t say the force doesn’t vary or the distance don’t vary. As the planet moves away the force decreases and so does the speed. As the planet turns back force increase and so is the speed.

Comment: So what did you mean by constant field?

Comment: @J.G. You mentioned the orbit shape so I asked how that shape forms.

Comment: By solving the Binet equation subject to initial conditions that almost surely prevent its being a circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both magnetic and gravitational forces work (with caveats not relevant to your question) according to the [Inverse Square Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law). Double the distance between interacting things, and you get a fourth of the force. Half the distance, and you get four times the force.

You can really see that with magnets. If you move one magnet closer to another, the force between them gets bigger faster. The force between magnets that are an inch apart is 144 times higher than between magnets that are a foot apart.

The reason it doesn't SEEM like that for gravity is because it's hard to double or half the distance to something when our current distance from the center of the earth is around 4,000 miles. It's pretty tough to double or half that distance in our everyday lives.

Comment: There are no magnetic monopoles. So the force between two magnetic dipoles is the lowest order force. That means that the force goes down by $1/r^4$, not $1/r^2$. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole in the Forces Between Two Magnetic Dipoles section

Comment: or see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets, which the answer to the magnetic side of your question.

Comment: O yes! We can see the behaviour of this law because it’s small. To see the behaviour with respect to earth which is huge we need to get in the range of 2000-8000 miles. Thanks. It’s amazing to see it.

Comment: I mean, to be fair, actual real world magnets aren't ideal magnetic dipoles of zero size, nor are they always going to be perfect cylinders of infinite length aligned exactly on their common axis (which gives an inverse-square law according to an elliptic integral I'm too lazy to do myself https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Force_between_two_bar_magnets). So technically, REAL magnets don't obey EITHER a $1/r^4$ NOR a $1/r^2$ law, but I'm pretty sure for the purposes of the question, that sort of nuance is more distracting than useful.

Answer (score 0):

Gravitational field strength is not constant. The value of Earth's gravitational field strength is generally take to as:
$$g=9.8ms^{-2}$$
However, this is at the surface of Earth (and this too varies from location to location; however, in most cases we assume it to be constant).

The gravitational field strength of any body does vary with distance. Limiting ourselves to Newtonian-gravitation, we can define the gravitational force as follows:
$$F_g=\frac{GM_1M_2}{r^2}$$

Where $F_g$ is the distance between two masses, $G$ is the gravitational constant, $M_1$ and $M_2$ are the masses of the two bodies and $r$ is the distance between the centers of the two bodies. Generally while using this formula, we make a few assumptions, such as - (1) Both the bodies are spherical and (2) Both the bodies are point masses.

From this formula, you can see that $F_g$ varies linearly with $r^{-2}$, that is if $r$ increases, $F_g$ decreases and vice-versa.

From this, the formula for gravitational field strength of a body can also be derived:
$$F_g=\frac{GM_1M_2}{r^2}$$
$$\implies M_2a=\frac{GM_1M_2}{r^2}$$
Where $a$ is the acceleration due to gravity of mass $M_2$ (we are considering the force that acts on mass $M_2$, the same can be done for mass $M_1$).
$$\implies a=\frac{GM_1}{r^2}$$
This is the formula for gravitational field strength of a body of mass $M_1$ at distance $r$ away from its center. We can even test it for Earth's gravitational field strength at its surface.

Earth's mass, $M_{\oplus}\approx 5.972\times 10^{24} kg$

Earth's radius, $R\approx 6.371\times 10^6 m$

Gravitational Constant, $G\approx 6.674\times 10^{-11} ms^{-2}$

$$a=\frac{GM_1}{r^2}$$
$$\implies a=\frac{6.674\times 10^{-11}\times 5.972\times 10^{24}}{(6.371\times 10^6)^2}$$
$$\approx 9.81 ms^{-2}$$

As seen, this gives the value for Earth's gravitational field strength at its surface.